# Graphing various mathematical functions in Python

Tags: python, beginner, algorithm, mathematics

1) This code's task is to create graphs of various algebraic, logarithmic and trigonometric functions and relations using Python's `matplotlib.plyplot` module. Turning code into a graph is a process. First, I secure a list of `xs` using `set_width(width)`. Then I iterate through the list by substituting each `x` into the function's equation. The result is a same-length list of the ys of the xs. Now that I have the `xs` and the functions of the `xs`, I can plug the two list into `ply.plot()` and display the result. The exceptions to this process are the logarithmic and square root functions due to math domain errors.

2) How would I be able to graph a circle algebraically without creating two separate parts?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import math


def set_width(width):
    """Sets how many xs will be included in the graphs (\"width\" of the graph)"""
    return list(range(-width, width + 1))


def linear(width):
    """Graphs a linear function via slope intercept form"""
    xs = set_width(width)

    def ys(m=1.0, b=0):
        return [m * x + b for x in xs]

    '''
    "xs" and "ys" are not labeled "domain" and "range" because "all real numbers" will be limited to just a certain 
    list of xs and ys
    '''

    plt.plot(xs, ys())
    plt.plot(xs, ys(3, 2))
    plt.plot(xs, ys(5, -3))
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()


def quadratic(width):
    """Graphs a quadratic function via vertex form"""
    xs = set_width(width)

    def ys(a=1.0, h=0, k=0):
        return [a * (x - h) ** 2 + k for x in xs]

    plt.plot(xs, ys())
    plt.plot(xs, ys(1, 10, -50))
    plt.plot(xs, ys(-4))
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()


def exponential(width):
    """Graphs an exponential function"""
    xs = set_width(width)

    def ys(a=1.0, b=2.0, h=0, k=0):
        return [a * b ** (x - h) + k for x in xs]

    plt.plot(xs, ys())
    plt.plot(xs, ys(3, 2, 4, 20))
    plt.plot(xs, ys(5, 0.75))
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()


def absolute(width):
    """Graphs an absolute function"""
    xs = set_width(width)

    def ys(a=1.0, h=0, k=0):
        return [a * abs(x - h) + k for x in xs]

    plt.plot(xs, ys())
    plt.plot(xs, ys(4, 7))
    plt.plot(xs, ys(-0.5, -4, -15))
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()


def square_root(width):
    """Graphs a square root function"""
    def transform(a=1.0, h=0, k=0):
        xs = [x for x in set_width(width) if x - h >= 0]
        ys = [a * np.sqrt(x - h) + k for x in xs]
        return xs, ys

    parent = transform()
    plt.plot(parent[0], parent[1])
    twice_r5 = transform(2, 5)
    plt.plot(twice_r5[0], twice_r5[1])
    half_l2_u5 = transform(.5, -2, 5)
    plt.plot(half_l2_u5[0], half_l2_u5[1])
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()


def cube_root(width):
    """Graphs a cube root function"""
    xs = set_width(width)

    def ys(a=1.0, h=0, k=0):
        return [a * np.cbrt(x - h) + k for x in xs]

    plt.plot(xs, ys())
    plt.plot(xs, ys(-3, 0, 1))
    plt.plot(xs, ys(2, 4, -3))
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()


def sideways_parabola(height):
    """Graphs a sideways parabola (quadratic relation)"""
    ys = set_width(height)

    def xs(a=1.0, h=0, k=0):
        return [a * (y - k) ** 2 + h for y in ys]

    plt.plot(xs(), ys)
    plt.plot(xs(3, 3, 3), ys)
    plt.plot(xs(-2, -7, 0), ys)
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()


def logarithms(width):
    """Graphs a logarithmic function"""
    def ys(b=2.0, a=1.0, h=0, k=0):
        xs = [x for x in set_width(width) if x - h > 0]
        ys = [a * math.log(x - h, b) + k for x in xs]
        return xs, ys

    parent = ys()
    plt.plot(parent[0], parent[1])
    three_r3 = ys(3, 2, 1000)
    plt.plot(three_r3[0], three_r3[1])
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()


def sine(width):
    """Graphs a sine function"""
    xs = set_width(width)

    def ys(a=1.0, h=0, k=0):
        return [a * np.sin(x - h) + k for x in xs]

    plt.plot(xs, ys())
    plt.plot(xs, ys(3, 5))
    plt.plot(xs, ys(0.5, 0, -3))
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()


def cosine(width):
    """Graphs a cosine function"""
    xs = set_width(width)

    def ys(a=1.0, h=0, k=0):
        return [a * np.cos(x - h) + k for x in xs]

    plt.plot(xs, ys())
    plt.plot(xs, ys(-1))
    plt.plot(xs, ys(2, 7, 9))
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()


def tangent(width):
    """Graphs the tangent function"""
    xs = set_width(width)

    def ys(a=1.0, h=0, k=0):
        return [a * math.tan(x - h) + k for x in xs]

    plt.plot(xs, ys())
    plt.plot(xs, ys(1, -10))
    plt.plot(xs, ys(6, -8, 20))
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()


linear(15)
quadratic(15)
exponential(7)
absolute(15)
square_root(16)
cube_root(27)
sideways_parabola(15)
logarithms(10000)
sine(15)
cosine(15)
tangent(25)
```

Comment: What is your objective here - to get a review, or to fix up the _exceptions to this process [, the] math domain errors_ ?

Comment: OK; well keep in mind that CodeReview policy requires working code. If this code is "working enough" for reviewers to be able to meaningfully run it and suggest improvements, fine; but break-fix is off-topic.

Comment: @Reinderien It is working code. The logarithmic and square root functions are just coded differently due to math domain errors.

Comment: @miAK Apart from logarithmic and square root functions, rest of the functions have very similar structure. Wouldn't it be much more cleaner if you make one plot function and input different arguments for different plots?

Answer (score 1):

### Usage of numpy

You have it as an `import`, but there are places where you could benefit from using it where you currently aren't.

For one,

```
list(range(-width, width + 1))
```

should use [`arange`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.arange.html?highlight=arange#numpy.arange).

```
[m * x + b for x in xs]
```

should not use a list comprehension; instead,

```
m*xs + b
```

where `xs` is an `ndarray`. Your other list comprehensions in the graphing functions should be likewise vectorized.